# How can I get a time axis onto an object, using D3?

Tags: d3.js

I'm very new to d3 and trying to learn by building a visualization.

My goal right now is to make a circle and color the circle based on some temporal data. I've made the circle, and want to add a timescale to it. The circle I have created fine using d3.arc() on an svg element. I have also created a time scale (seen below). My question is, how can I "attach" this time scale to the circle? I want to be able to say that at xyz point in time, my data holds this value, so now color the circle based on a color scale.

Or...am I going about this wrong?

```
var time = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
                return d.date;
            }))
```

Comment: If you wanted to use time scale. You need to use `d3.time.scale()`. More info [**here**](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales). If you still need help. Please provide a fiddle with complete codes in it.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. Something like in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20826989/d3-scatterplot-using-time-scale-on-x-axis-not-working-in-firefox)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to use a quantitative scale instead of ordinal.
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales says -

> Ordinal scales have a discrete domain, such as a set of names or categories

and in your code, you use the "extent" of the date property, which only gives you 2 values - the earliest and most recent date in your data. That *is* a discrete domain, but a very limited one, and wouldn't represent your data very well. The scale will only output at most 2 values.

```
var now = Date.now();
var then = now - 1000;

var colors = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain([then, now])
    .range(['#ff0000','#0000ff']);

colors(then);      // red
colors(now);       // blue
colors(now - 500); // red... expecting violet
```

change 'ordinal' to 'linear' and leave the rest as is.

```
var now = Date.now();
var then = now - 1000;

var colors = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([then, now])
    .range(['#ff0000','#0000ff']);

colors(then);      // red
colors(now);       // blue
colors(now - 500); // violet
```

The tricky part (at least for me) was remembering that the output of d3.scale.linear() (the 'colors' variable above) is a function. It can be called just like any other function.

```
var fakeData = d3.range(then, now, 10);

var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr({ height: 500, width: 500 });

var circle = svg.append('circle')
    .attr({ r: 100, cx: 250, cy: 250 });

function changeTime(time){
    circle.attr('fill', colors(time));
}
```